# Is it possible to find relative path locators for desktop application (non - web app) automation using appium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, appium, appium-desktop

For automating non-web applications like desktop app (eg calculator, taskmanager), the element locator for these type of apps are of absolute path. Sample xpath is mentioned below.

Is there a possibility to find and use **relative path** for non-web apps.

Kindly provide your comments. Thanks in advance.

```
"/AXApplication[@AXTitle='Calculator']/AXWindow[0]/AXGroup[1]/AXButton[@AXDescription='clear']"
"/XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name=\"IntegrationApp\"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeDatePicker/XCUIElementTypePicker/XCUIElementTypePickerWheel[1]"
```

Comment: The XPath you've provided looks relative to me (@ are used)... Absolute XPath look like : `html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[3]` Perhaps you meant to shorten your existing XPath expression ? Which is of course possible.

Comment: Yes, I am looking ways to shorten and simplify the locator. May I know how it is possible?

Comment: Inspect the code and look for specific patterns (repetition of same elements, specific text or attribute in an element) to generate a unique and short XPath expression.  Also, you can simplify your XPath with `//`.Please provide a sample of your data if you need assistance. For example your second XPath expression could be replaced with : `/XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name=\"IntegrationApp\"]//XCUIElementTypePickerWheel[1]`

Comment: Yes, Usage of double slash // and patterns helps in shortening the XPath. But can it be applied to a desktop application? Here is a sample locator of a desktop app (Calculator) and the AppiumForMac driver info link. "/AXApplication[@AXTitle='Calculator']/AXMenuBarItems/AXMenuBarItem[@AXTitle='View']/AXMenu/AXMenuItem[@AXTitle='Scientific']"
 https://github.com/appium/appium-for-mac

Comment: Well, AppiumforMac uses a special kind of XPath. It's very specific. "Classic" Appium supports standard XPath (`//`, wildcards, ...) http://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/migrating-to-xcuitest/#xpath-locator-strategy. So, finding a relative and short XPath locator shouldn't be a problem in a desktop application if XPath 1.0 (preferably not a subset) is supported.